# Исправление PERL-запроса для парсинга данных из tcpdump

Tags: linux, парсер, perl, tcpdump

коллеги.
Есть запрос:

```
tcpdump -e -tt -nn
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью него мы получаем точное время с долями секунды (6 знаков после запятой).
Далее мы форматируем запрос PERLом, после чего доли секунды исчезают, остается только целая часть.

```
tcpdump -e -tt -nn | perl -pe 's/([0-9]*)\..*length\s([0-9]*):\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+)\s>\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+).*/$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6/' > traffic.log
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить запрос, чтобы остались доли секунд?

Comment: А что вам pcap файл не разбирается? Он элементарный и микросекунды сразу байтами

Comment: На будущее, приводи текстовую информацию текстом...

Comment: И зачем вам `perl`?! Визуализаций pcap существует множество, хотя бы тот же Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно:

```
tcpdump -e -tt -nn | \
  perl -pe 's/(\d*\.\d*)\s.*length\s([0-9]*):\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+)\s>\s((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\.(\d+).*/$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить первую группу

```
([0-9]*)
```

на

```
([0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{6})
```

Тогда первая группа будет содержать полную запись времени